Adding Animations and control it by pressing didn't work - Visual Studio 2022 & Unity
I have a question I didn't find the right answer for.
I am new to coding and I try to make my first character and want to do and know about good controlling and animations first.
But I am stuck at an "error". The character isn't working so far, but I don't know how I can add a new animation like "dodge" or "shoot" because it will always run an an old animation or in the dodge animation the character will jump and stuff like that.
I really don't know if I am using the wrong code or if I have a simple error.
I hope someone can help.
I will add my movement.cs so you can see the whole script.
The "error" is on the //Character is dodging where I want to start the dodge animation
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationSpeed;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpHeight;

    [SerializeField]
    private float gravityMultiplier;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpHorizontalSpeed;

    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpButtonGracePeriod;

    [SerializeField]
    private float dodgeButtonGracePeriod;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    private Animator animator;
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private float ySpeed;
    private float originalStepOffset;
    private float? lastGroundedTime;
    private float? jumpButtonPressedTime;
    private float? dodgeButtonPressedTime;
    private bool isJumping;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool isDodging;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        originalStepOffset = characterController.stepOffset;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Character Movement
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movementDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput);
        float inputMagnitude = Mathf.Clamp01(movementDirection.magnitude);

        //Movement Slow
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightShift))
        {
            inputMagnitude /= 2;
        }

        //Blend of Animation - Idle,Walk, run - BlendTreeMovement
        animator.SetFloat("Input Magnitude", inputMagnitude, 0.05f, Time.deltaTime);

        //Movement Z & X Direction
        movementDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * movementDirection;
        movementDirection.Normalize();

        //Speed Y-Direction based on gravity & jumpButtonpressed
        float gravity = Physics.gravity.y * gravityMultiplier;
        ySpeed += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            lastGroundedTime = Time.time;
        }
        
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jumpButtonPressedTime = Time.time;
        }

        if (Time.time - lastGroundedTime <= jumpButtonGracePeriod)
        {
            characterController.stepOffset = originalStepOffset;
            ySpeed = -0.5f;
            animator.SetBool("isGrounded", true);
            isGrounded = true;
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            isJumping = false;
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);
            animator.SetBool("isDodging", false);
            isDodging = false;

            if (Time.time - jumpButtonPressedTime <= jumpButtonGracePeriod)
            {
                ySpeed = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3 * gravity);
                animator.SetBool("isJumping", true);
                isJumping = true;
                jumpButtonPressedTime = null;
                lastGroundedTime = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            characterController.stepOffset = 0;
            animator.SetBool("isGrounded", false);
            isGrounded = false;

            if ((isJumping && ySpeed < 0) || ySpeed < -2)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isFalling", true);
            }
        }

        //Character isDodging NOT RIGHT -> HERE IS THE ERROR !
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Dodge"))
        {
            dodgeButtonPressedTime = Time.time;
        }

        if (Time.time - lastGroundedTime <= dodgeButtonGracePeriod)
        {
            characterController.stepOffset = originalStepOffset;
            ySpeed = -0.5f;
            animator.SetBool("isGrounded", true);
            isGrounded = true;
            animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            isJumping = false;
            animator.SetBool("isDodging", false);
            isDodging = false;
            animator.SetBool("isFalling", false);

            if (Time.time - dodgeButtonPressedTime <= dodgeButtonGracePeriod)
            {
                ySpeed = 2;
                animator.SetBool("isDodging", true);
                isDodging = true;
                dodgeButtonPressedTime = null;
                lastGroundedTime = null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            characterController.stepOffset = 0;
            animator.SetBool("isGrounded", false);
            isGrounded = false;

            if ((isDodging && ySpeed < -0.1) || ySpeed < -2)
            {
                animator.SetBool("isDodging", true);
            }
        }

        //Character isMoving
        if (movementDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isMoving", true);

            Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(movementDirection, Vector3.up);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("isMoving", false);
        }

        if (isGrounded == false)
        {
            Vector3 velocity = movementDirection * inputMagnitude * jumpHorizontalSpeed;
            velocity.y = ySpeed;

            characterController.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    //Slope Methode
    private Vector3 AdjustVelocityToSlope(Vector3 velocity)
    {
        var ray = new Ray(transform.position, Vector3.down);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hitInfo, 0.2f))
        {
            var slopeRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hitInfo.normal);
            var adjustedVelocity = slopeRotation * velocity;

            if (adjustedVelocity.y < 0)
            {
                return adjustedVelocity;
            }
        }

        return velocity;       
    }

    //Movement Character-Controller - RootMotion
    private void OnAnimatorMove()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            Vector3 velocity = animator.deltaPosition;
            velocity = AdjustVelocityToSlope(velocity);

            //Charactermovement same speed every Time/Frame
            velocity.y += ySpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            characterController.Move(velocity);
        }
    }

    private void OnApplicationFocus(bool focus)
    {
        if (focus)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        }
    }
}

I need help for the script to trigger the right animation without jumping or dead end

well, if you jump, and you dont watch them to crouch, you need some for of "is jumping" so when someone presses crouch, it checks if not jumping or sprinting or whatever else you want to exclude, then set crouching...
